# how to make bot assign roles when given command

Tags: discord.py

i am trying to make the bot give the 'mall' role and remove the 'study hall' role. However, it keeps returning the error

> Ignoring exception in on_message
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\frost\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
> await coro(*args, **kwargs)
> File "D:\GalaxyConflux Master\gcclient.py", line 89, in on_message
> role.id = 798193741403127818
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

the code that is running is this

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(gccmd.cmd_prfx + 'mall'):
        role = 'Mall'
        role.id = 798193741403127818
        await message.author.add_roles(role.id)
```

i have tried many different approaches but each result in a similar error.
I had it just go off of the role = 'Mall' part but that did not work either.

How can I convert the role id into an actual id?

Thanks so much!
~Glimmer

Answer (score 0):

here's an example peice that shows you how to add a role and remove one.

```
@client.command()
async def mall(ctx):
    # if prefix is '-' you'd type: -mall
    await user.remove_roles(@ROLE_ID)
    await user.add_roles(@ROLE_ID)
    await ctx.send("Mall role added!")

@client.command()
async def home(ctx):
    # if prefix is '-' you'd type: -home
    await user.remove_roles(@ROLE_ID)
    await user.add_roles(@ROLE_ID)
    await ctx.send("Home role added!")
```

If you want to remove multiple roles, you'd have to just add all of the roles there you want to remove, then add the one's you want.

For example, if you are heading to the mall from your house, it removes every role including the house role and adds the mall one.

Comment: This needs the `discord.Member` and `discord.Role` typehints, otherwise the same thing will happen.

Comment: i want to make it so a user can do it themselves, like if they wanted the mall role they could type something like.
-goto mall
its supposed to be like movement, where they MOVE to the new channel and leave the old one.

would this be possible?

Comment: I just edited it. Is this what you were looking for? If not, I think you need to clarify what you exactly need a bit more.